# Angular routing resolver execute twice

Tags: angular

I do have angular 10 application and added routing resolver for one of its competent. When I navigate to the resolver added component via different service, observed that routing resolver is calling twice for each request (problem is not the routing resolver is not working, but its executing twice per request)

**customer-resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private serviceApi: ApiService,
        private stateService: StateService
    ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<any> {
        return this.persistToState();
    }

    private async persistToState(): Promise<void> {
        let custId = this.stateService.custId;
        const data = await this.serviceApi.getCustomerData(custId);
        this.stateService.customerData = data;
    }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { ... },
  {
    path: "customer",
    component: CustomerComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateCustomer],
    resolve: { cust: CustomerResolver }
  },
  { ... }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Any hint why routing resolver get execute twice ?

Comment: show some of your code.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan added some code the question

Comment: Check the returning value in persistToState(): Promise<void>  is missing.
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: @JuanPabloMorenoMartín async function is always returning a promise

Answer (score 0):

this is apparently a known issue, after few searches I found the following that may be helpful,
Note, If I use page refresh the issue shows resolver "receives" two calls as a result of HttpClient.get(..)
But if you use a new tab, or on new browser window, it only receives the results once, and if you refresh, it gets twice,
Apparently it is an activeRouter issue, and I hope they get it fixed.
in my case, this problem shows only if there is non-200OK! status returned from the backend server, in successful (200OK) results, I only get 1 result, I am not sure about your particular case.
[Check here for known bug issue since router 3.2.0 onward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930756/angular2-resolver-instantiated-multiple-times)

Conclusion, the behavior can be described as
The resolver catches the error twice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).